# gnuplot - How to make zmin equal to zmax keeeping autoscale on z axis

Tags: gnuplot

How one could make resulting output of scaling over z axis symmetric over xy plane: zmax = zmin, keeping autoscale on z axis turning on? (GNUplot 5.0)

[resulting graph - 3d-polar.png](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103124769/3d-polar.png)

Is there this possibility in GNUplot or only fixed range of cbrange can be used?

the example that is used for polar heatmap plot:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800
set output '3d-polar.png'
set lmargin at screen 0.05
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

set pm3d map
unset key
set multiplot

set parametric
set grid xtics ytics

set angles degree
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
set autoscale zfix
set palette model RGB defined ( 0"black", 1"white", 2"grey")
splot '_FullWV.dat' u ($2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):3
unset multiplot
```

The _FullWV.dat file is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103124769/_FullWV.dat).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stats` to extract min and max of the 3rd column, and define cbrange accordingly.

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800
set output '3d-polar.png'
set lmargin at screen 0.05
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

set pm3d map
unset key
set multiplot

stats '_FullWV.dat' using 3
max(a,b) = (a>b) ? a : b

Z_MAX = max(-STATS_min, STATS_max)

set parametric
set grid xtics ytics

set angles degree
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
#set zrange [-Z_MAX : Z_MAX]
set cbrange [-Z_MAX : Z_MAX]

set palette model RGB defined ( 0"black", 1"white", 2"grey")
splot '_FullWV.dat' u ($2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):3
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! in order to close the question - do you know how to _replace_ the output png file during replotting?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day)

Comment: It'll be very kind of you if you could help with another tricky [puzzle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675253/gnuplot-how-to-scale-xyrange-to-not-take-into-account-small-z-in-heatmap-plot). I'll be glad to upvote as soon as I'll be allowed to (when my reputation here exceeds 15 points)