# Gnuplot - how to scale xyrange to not take into account small z in heatmap plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file [_FullWV.dat](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103124769/_FullWV.dat) and I want Gnuplot to automatically scale xyrange if outside the wanted region z < 10^(-8), is there any way to make it?

Graph is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103124769/3d-polar2.png).

The used [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656069/gnuplot-how-to-make-zmin-equal-to-zmax-keeeping-autoscale-on-z-axis) is below:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800
set output '3d-polar.png'
set lmargin at screen 0.05
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

set pm3d map
unset key
set multiplot

stats '_FullWV.dat' using 3
max(a,b) = (a>b) ? a : b

Z_MAX = max(-STATS_min, STATS_max)

set parametric
set grid xtics ytics

set angles degree
set autoscale xfix
set autoscale yfix
#set zrange [-Z_MAX : Z_MAX]
set cbrange [-Z_MAX : Z_MAX]

set palette model RGB defined ( 0"black", 1"white", 2"grey")
splot '_FullWV.dat' u ($2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):3
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20360672 ?

Comment: @maij : No, it wouldn't work. You need to check if z<1e-8 for every data point, and cannot set the range before the plot.

Comment: @EricDuminil : He already uses `stats` to get min and max before the plot. So he can set the ranges before the plot..

Comment: @maij: Please try it, I don't think it can be done with the if statement you linked. stats gives you zmin and zmax, but doesn't give you any information about x and y coordinates where z is close to 0.

Comment: @EricDuminil : Ah, I understand. He only wants to skip the **specific** points x,y,z with z<1e-8. I thought, he wants to restrict x- and yrange if **any** of the points has z<1e-8. Now I also understand how your answer is related to the question :)

Comment: @maij: The EricDuminil's answer is exactly that I needed, because the points in the inside region with abs(z)<10^(-3), of course, are important for plot

Comment: @EricDuminil: seems I again need your help, could you shed some light on [it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40847898/4792427)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Code

```
set size ratio -1
splot '_FullWV.dat' u (abs($3)<1e-5 ? NaN : $2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):3
```

1e-8 was too small, it cut almost nothing from the original range.

## Explanation

```
abs($3)<1e-5 ? NaN : $2*cos($1)
```

If z (3rd column) is between -1e-5 and 1e-5, leave x undefined (Not a Number). If x is undefined, no point will be displayed, even if y and z are defined.

If z is outside this range, define x as `$2*cos($1)`.

Note that for pm3d, at least 2 consecutive values are needed for a point to be displayed. It means that 1 lone value will be take into account by autoscale, but will not be displayed.

```
set size ratio -1
```

means that one unit on the x scale will be as big as one unit on the y scale : a circle might be displayed as an ellipse otherwise.

Comment: Thanks again) what is the syntax of those "conditional" plotting?