# Gnuplot Surface plot combined with heatmap on the same plot in polar coordinates

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot 3D surface plot combined with heatmap plot of the same function (from [file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103124769/_FullWV.dat) data) at the bottom (like in the chapter "Combining surfaces with images" in  [Gnuplot Cookbook](https://computacion1fcienciasunam.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/gnuplot-cookbook.pdf])).

The wanted picture looks like [this](http://www.nature.com/article-assets/npg/ncomms/2016/161005/ncomms12820/images/m685/ncomms12820-f1.jpg) and [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/103124769/3D_polar_plot.png).

Contour plot is plotted with the [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675253/gnuplot-how-to-scale-xyrange-to-not-take-into-account-small-z-in-heatmap-plot).

Is it possible to draw two graphs (contour and 3D) in the polar coordinates in one plot via Gnuplot?

Output is nothing, so there is an error in the code:

```
reset
set terminal pngcairo size 800,800 enhanced font 'Verdana,20'
set output '3d-polar_AbsPsiSquared.png'

set lmargin at screen 0.05
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set bmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9

set pm3d
unset key
set multiplot

stats '_FullWV.dat' using ($3*$3+$4*$4)
max(a,b) = (a>b) ? a : b
round2(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)
round(x, n) = round2(x*10**n)*10.0**(-n)

Z_MAX = max(-STATS_min, STATS_max)
Z_MAX = round(Z_MAX,1)

set parametric
set grid xtics ytics
set angles degree

#set zrange[-1,1]
#set cbrange [-1:1]
set autoscale fix
#set autoscale xfix
#set autoscale yfix
set autoscale zfix
#set autoscale
set cbrange [-Z_MAX : Z_MAX]

set palette model RGB defined ( 0"#6495ED", 1"blue", 2"#00008B",3"white",\
     4"green",5"yellow",6"red")
#splot '_FullWV.dat' u ($2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):($3*$3+$4*$4)
set size ratio -1
set hidden front
set xyplane at -1
splot '_FullWV.dat' u (abs(($3*$3+$4*$4))<1e-3 ? NaN : $2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):($3*$3+$4*$4) with pm3d at b, '_FullWV.dat' u (abs(($3*$3+$4*$4))<1e-3 ? NaN : $2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):($3*$3+$4*$4) with pm3d

unset multiplot
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @EricDuminil: updated the question -- I've just tried to change the existing script in order to add the surface plot on it, but output is not produced (although Gnuplot doesn't show any error messages)

Comment: Is it another `_FullWV.dat` file than for the other questions? There are only 3 columns, and you are referencing a 4th one with `$4`

Comment: you are right, the new file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ikn201myvho152/_FullWV1.dat?dl=0). I saw some output with the Total Commander Viewer (and it is almost what I want), but other viewers don't show it, could be there some problems with margins?

Comment: Do you have a smaller subset of the data?

Comment: Updated data file with smaller number of points

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129269/discussion-between-eugene-smit-and-eric-duminil).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, the solution is depthorder option of pm3d, so the right script is:

```
reset
set terminal postscript eps size 5,6 enhanced color font 'Helvetica,20' linewidth 2
set output "3d.eps"

set tics scale 1.25

set xlabel '{/Helvetica-Oblique x, a.u.}'
set ylabel '{/Helvetica-Oblique y, a.u.}'
set zlabel '{/Helvetica-Oblique E, a.u.}'

set pm3d depthorder
unset key
set multiplot
unset colorbox

stats '_FullWV.dat' using ($3*$3+$4*$4)
max(a,b) = (a>b) ? a : b
round2(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)
round(x, n) = round2(x*10**n)*10.0**(-n)

Z_MAX = max(-STATS_min, STATS_max)
Z_MAX = round(Z_MAX,1)

set parametric
set grid xtics ytics ztics
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set tics out
set decimalsign ","

set format x "%.1f"
set format y "%.1f"
set format z "%.0f"

set angles degree
set view 61,33
set ztics floor(Z_MAX/3)


set autoscale fix
set autoscale zfix
set cbrange [0 : Z_MAX]



set palette model RGB defined ( 0"#168de2", 1"#0201db", 2"#00008B", 3"#00dcf5",\
         4"#09df67",5"yellow",6"red")
set size ratio 1
set hidden3d front
set xyplane at -10
splot '_FullWV.dat' u (abs(($3*$3+$4*$4))<1e-3 ? NaN : $2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):($3*$3+$4*$4) with pm3d at b, '_FullWV.dat' u (abs(($3*$3+$4*$4))<1e-3 ? NaN : $2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):($3*$3+$4*$4) with pm3d

unset multiplot
```